# Weird SQL Server Management studio behavior

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssms

I am currently using SQL Server Management Studio (Ver 9.00.3042.00) and click the "New Query" and wrote the following code:

```
Select 
    colA,
    colB,
    colC
    colD
From
    table1
```

When I click the parse (checkbox) button to validate the SQL statement, it says "Command(s) completed successfully".  Isn't the parse button suppose to catch these simple errors...

Has anyone experienced this type of behavior from Management Studio?  This just started happening this week....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's because that is valid SQL. You're effectively aliasing colC with the name colD. It's the same as typing:

```
colC as colD
```

Edit: For what it's worth, this is one of the reasons why people will argue that you should put the commas at the beginning of the line in cases like this. It's a lot easier to spot gotchas like this when the code is formatted as such:

```
Select 
    colA
    , colB
    , colC
    colD
From
    table1
```

Comment: When I try to parse a select statement that was missing a comma in a stored procedure is would throw a 'Incorrect syntax near colC'

Comment: That's because stored procedure parameters don't support this kind of aliasing, since they're not columns. SELECT columns do, however.

Comment: @Soren - I just tried the same behaviour in a stored procedure template and it passed the parse check.

Answer (score 0):

After a little playing around, it throws the "Incorrect syntax near" on the following code snippets

```
Select     
    colA,    
    colB    
    colC    
    colD
From    
    table1

Select     
    colA,    
    colB,    
    colC,    
    colD,
From    
    table1
```

Comment: As well it should -- in your original post, you created a column alias. In the top one here, that wouldn't play as you have two tokens after colB (colC, colD). In your bottom example, there is a genuine syntax error in that there is no valid select token after "colD," ... @Jeromy Irvine is right. :)